# How to control if a field should be serialized with Spring Boot based on active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have been looking for a way to be able to annotate my response models in Spring Boot with a custom annotation to control which field should be serialized using spring profiles and Jackson.

I know there is an existing annotation JsonView to define different views, but that would require logic to handle separate views for each model och enabling them.

I rather use a custom annotation which would take a (list of) profiles to exclude/include the field for.

I also looked into writing a Serializer, but that only controls the value, not the whole property, including the name.

Is this possible in some way?

```
class Response {

    var message: String

    @JsonExclude("production")
    var debugMessage: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to work on a higher level.

I suppose your Response is being serialized by a Webservice. Maybe you could have one implementation that send a Response with the @JsonExclude and one other without.

You enable the desired Webservice with @Profile annotation.

```
@RestController
@Profile("withExclude")
class WithExcludeController : IMyController {
  fun process() : ResponseWithExclude {
    // ...
  }
}

@RestController
@Profile("withoutExclude")
class WithoutExcludeController : IMyController {
  fun process() : ResponseWithoutExclude {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If a re-use any of my models in multiple Webservices/endpoints, wouldn't that require I duplicate all of these each with a activation profile which seems a lot of extra code?